# sftp: upload all files, directories and sub-directories contained in a folder

Tags: sftp, put

On machine A I have the folder

```
/home/a/
```

On machine B I have the folder

```
/home/b/
```

I wish transfer all files, directories and sub-directories of /home/a in /home/b with sftp
On machine A I tried the commands:

```
sftp fibon82@machineB.com
put /home/a/* /home/b/
```

but it doesn't work, i get the error message: "skipping non-regular file /home/a/a1"... [a1 is a sub-directory of a]
How could I modify the put instruction?

Thanks! :)

## EDIT:

I solved using scp:

```
scp -r /home/a/ fibon82@machineB.com:/home/b/
```

Comment: `put -r` would have worked too.

Comment: Ok but how could I know that for "put command" the option -r is available?  If I look [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/sftp.htm) only the flag -P is described... The same in the [manual](http://www.r3v0.net/docs/Delta/man/sftp.html)  Thanks! :)

Comment: You should post that as an answer instead.

Comment: Yes. Instead of EDITing your question with the answer, you should answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @fibon82 For up-to-date manual to OpenSSH `sftp`, refer to the [OpenSSH project](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/sftp.1).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Although not strictly equivalent to sftp, [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) is a very powerful alternative for scp and sftp, especially when updating the copies from machine A to machine B, as it doesn't copy the files that haven't been altered; it's also able to remove files from machine B that have been deleted from machine A (only when it's told to of course).

In your case, the syntax would be

```
rsync -zrp /home/a/ user@remote.host.com:/home/b/
```

The `-r` option is for recursively copying files, `-z` enables compression during the transfer, and `-p` preserves the file permissions (file creation, edit, etc.) when copying, which is something that scp doesn't do AFAIK. Many more options are possible; as usual, read the `man` pages.

Comment: Ah thank you! :)  A new thing that I learned!

Comment: @fibon82: You're welcome :)

Comment: i love you, i synced 400MB of data in 1 minute by just using your code. I would add you should also use --progress otherwise you'll be staring at nothing without knowing what's happening (and at what speed :) )

Comment: Sadly `rsync` does not speak `sftp`-Protocol.  So if you set up an [`sftp`-chroot using `ssh`'s build in `internal-sftp`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot) then `rsync` fails.

Answer (score 33):

In `sftp` this command recursively uploads content of the current directory to the remote current directory:

```
 put -r .
```

See [`man sftp`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/sftp.1?query=sftp&sec=1).

Comment: The `-r` switch is supported since [OpenSSH 5.4](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4) only.

Comment: Note that the `-r` switch is client side only (part of `sftp` command).  So the server (here: receiving) side does not need OpenSSH 5.4, only the client needs to support it.

Comment: This should be the answer! It simply works for uploading an entire directory tree.

Answer (score 10):

`scp` (secure copy) is the Linux de facto for transferring files over a secure tunnel. In your case you would want to use the recursive switch, e.g.:

```
scp -r /home/a/ user@remote.host.com:/home/b/
```

Comment: sftp and scp are actually different protocols, both based on ssh.

Comment: Yes, if the server only allows sftp protocol, this answer does not work.

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
put -r /home/a/ /home/b/
```

for more info check out: [this](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/06/secure-file-transfer-using-sftp.html)

Comment: The `-r` switch is supported since [OpenSSH 5.4](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.4) only.

Comment: Note that the `-r` switch is client side only (part of `sftp` command).  So the server (here: receiving) side does not need OpenSSH 5.4, only the client needs to support it.  And: **This should be the accepted answer**, as getting (the possibly unsupported) `rsync` as answer to a question tagged `sftp` is a bit confusing.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it copies `a/` inside `b/`, but only if `b/a/` already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, put -r should work. But the destintion folder needs to be present on your remote host:

```
sftp> put -r sourcefolder
 Uploading sourcefolder/ to /user/folder
 Couldn't canonicalize: No such file or directory
 ....
sftp> mkdir sourcefolder
sftp> put -r sourcefolder
 Uploading sourcefolder/ to /user/folder/sourcefolder
 Entering sourcefolder/
 sourcefolder/file1
 sourcefolder/file2
```

Comment: Have you added reference and proof supporting what you state and confirmed this answer is not already answered in one of the existing answers on the post. Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Answer (score -1):

In my case `rsync` wasn't possible so I used:

```
mput -rp /home/a/ /home/b/
```

Comment: There's no `mput` command in OpenSSH `sftp`. Maybe you refer to `psftp`?